# Find the Nth unique value and return to dataframe in Python

Tags: python, pandas, unique

I have the following pandas data frames:

df1

```
Out 1 Out 2 Out 3 Out 4 Out 5
3     1     2     4     5
100  50    200    300   200
```

The values in df1 represent the Nth unique values in df2$ID. So the 1st unique value is 999, the 3rd unique value is 777 etc.

```
ID  ID2
999 888
101 801
777 666
777 666
555 100
555 100
111 100
```

So for a final df3 I need the following: Note I've only updated the first row for the example

```
Out 1 Out 2 Out 3 Out 4 Out 5
777   999   101   555   111
100  50    200    300   200
```

I have tried using the answer by @Wen, but it creates the following error: I couldn't find an answer to this one, beyond it may be an indexing error. I have also made sure I converted relevant data types to int32 to no avail. Any help would be much appreciated -

```
ValueError: Row labels must have same size as column labels
```

Comment: Pandas use numpy, so you can just do `np.unique(df2['ID'])[df1.iloc[0,:]]`

Comment: Thanks for this - I had a slight index issue previously in the code which is why I didn't upvote it earlier. Works well!

Answer (score 1):

You can `drop_duplicates` and using `lookup`

```
s=df2.drop_duplicates('ID').reset_index(drop=True)

df1.iloc[0,:]=s.lookup(df1.iloc[0,:]-1,['ID']*len(s))
df1
Out[222]: 
   Out1  Out2  Out3  Out4  Out5
0   777   999   101   555   111
1   100    50   200   300   200
```

Comment: I'm getting the following error: `NameError: name 'row_labels' is not defined`- does this have something to do with indexing? –